# How to timeout after few minuts a checkout session in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, checkout

In my firebase web app I need to set up a checkout session than last max 10min. Stripe cannot do that as the checkout session has a minimum expiration time of 1h. Are there other options available or a way to overcome this limitation?
 I basically need my app to handle only one checkout session at a time and only once a session is completed then a new user can make a new purchase request. I therfore I need to impose a short timeout for the checkout.

EDIT: another option would be to cancel all the created checkout sessions as soon as one is succesful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not supported. If you want to enforce such a time limit, you'll need to build a custom payment flow to achieve this.

If you can provide more context around *why* you want to structure your payments serially like this, perhaps we can offer some alternative approaches.

**Update**: Not long after this answer, Stripe released the `/expire` endpoint ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/expire)) for Checkout session, allowing you to explicitly "cancel" a session.

Depending on the exact situation you have with parallel customers and payments, you should also consider using manual capture in case two customer manage to pay before you can expire the sessions. Manual capture would allow you to evaluate a completed payment and check for others before capturing the payment.

Comment: I can offer the service only to one customer at a time. As soon as one customer pays I need to cancel all the checkout sessions that are active. I am using the pre-built checkout page ( using stripe.checkout.sessions.create) and then I use a webhook to listen for the event "paid" (event checkout.session.completed). Once I receive one "paid" event I then need to cancel all the checkout sessions that are active and I am stuck at this specific last step.

Comment: It seems to be your lucky day, because Stripe just released this new endpoint to expire a session: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/expire